# развернуть готовый проект-сайт на python

Tags: html, python, django, html5, вёрстка

пришел проект Бэк которого написан на питоне джанго, пытаюсь развернуть его на локальном сервере, дабы внести корректировки в верстку, index.html открываю, а он не видит стили [image: не видит стили]

объясните старому что сделать для того чтобы развернуть проект у себя?

Comment: `python manage.py runserver` и переходите на `localhost:8000`.

Comment: можете пожалуйста объяснить подробнее где это вводить и как , я никогда не работал с python

Comment: Вводить в консоли из корня проекта (где файл `manage.py`). Но это вполне может не заработать, потому что неизвестно, какие зависимости требуются. Лучше такие вопросы задавать тому, кто Вам предоставил проект. Для развёрнутого ответа информации пока не хватает.

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: Не за что) Если добавите больше информации, постараюсь дать более точный ответ. *P. S.: чтобы упомянуть участника, используйте `@`. Пример: `@nomnoms12`.*

Comment: @nomnoms12 я знаю лишь то что Админ панель на django, сайт самописный , пытался развернуть через runserver ,но SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Otm.su/ore/index/apps.py on line 6, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: А этот проект вообще рабочий? Странно, что при запуске возникает такая ошибка. Фиксится добавлением `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` в начало `ore/index/apps.py`.

Comment: @nomnoms12 рабочий сайт https://otm.su/